# Safari not showing text on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I am using my company's slider plugin. It works great on all browsers, *except* for Safari on Mac. The problem that happens is that, while the image shows up, the white text on the image that's supposed to appear on the right does **not** show up on initial load **but** if you resize the window, it suddenly appears.

Here is the site:

http://redners.wpengine.com/ (only the sliders 2,3 and 5 have this text).

I tried setting backface-visibility in css and messing with the redraw function in jquery, but neither worked.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Are you using web fonts?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the description to specify, but the 2nd, 3rd and 5th have this text. The 1st and 4th don't, so maybe that's why you didn't see it. 

We are using web fonts, but this behavior still happens after I resize the window and then it moves on to the next slide and the new text doesn't appear, I don't think it's that.